# Why did Adrammelech and Sharezer suddenly kill their father King Sennacherib?

Tags: isaiah

In Isaiah 37, King Sennacherib tries to destroy the Northern two-tribe Kingdom, but Jehovah protects them from the Assyrian empire. King Sennacherib returns to Assyria, begins bowing down to his god Nisrock, but then is all of a sudden killed by his two sons.

It seems to be difficult to find much of a political context to all this — why did King Sennacherib's two sons suddenly kill him? Did they have some vendetta against him? It ended up being one of his other sons who got the throne also, so clearly inheriting the throne couldn't have been a reason either.

Comment: @Kyan Clay
I'm not sure you'll receive a biblical answer to this question, other then it was prophesied that he would die for attacking Jerusalem. Other then that you can go here http://www.ancient.eu/sennacherib/ for the historical reason for his assanation by his sons.

Answer (score 2):

### Suddenly, 20 years later ...

As a point of history, Sennacherib ruled the Assyrian empire from c.705 to 681 BCE.  His early years were marked by rebellion among his vassal kingdoms: Babylon in 703 and a large number of fortified cities in Syria-Palestine, including Jerusalem, in 701, all of which he put down.  Babylon [rebelled again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sennacherib#The_.22Babylonian_problem.22) and was finally plundered and destroyed in 689.  According to Assyrian records, [Sennacherib died](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sennacherib#Death) in the capital city in 681: he was either crushed under a temple statue or, more likely, murdered by assassination at the hand of his oldest living son, [Arda-Mulissi](http://www.gatewaystobabylon.com/introduction/murderersennacherib.htm) (who had been passed over as heir-designate).  Sennacherib was succeeded by his youngest son, [Esarhaddon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esarhaddon).

The three Hebrew Bible accounts that describe Sennacherib’s death place it immediately following the story of [Assyria’s siege of Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assyrian_Siege_of_Jerusalem) in 701.   [Isaiah 37](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nasb/isa/37/6/s_716006) describes Jerusalem on the verge of attack, when suddenly:

> “[T]he angel of the LORD went out and struck 185,000 in the camp of
>   the Assyrians; and when men arose early in the morning, behold, all of
>   these were dead.  So Sennacherib king of Assyria departed and returned
>   home and lived at Nineveh.  It came about as he was worshiping in the
>   house of Nisroch his god, that Adrammelech and Sharezer his sons
>   killed him with the sword; and they escaped into the land of Ararat.
>   And Esarhaddon his son became king in his place” (v.36-38).

The same story in 2 Kings follows Isaiah's account very closely ([19:35-37](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nasb/2ki/19/1/s_331001)) but adds an important detail: before the siege Hezekiah sent an envoy to Sennacherib surrendering Jerusalem and paying the demanded tribute of gold and silver (taken from Jerusalem’s temple and palace, [18:13-16](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nasb/2ki/18/1/s_331001)). And lastly, the account in [2Chr.32](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nasb/2ch/32/20/s_399020) omits the ransom but finishes Isaiah's story of the siege and Sennacherib’s death in abbreviated form.

Whatever prompted Assyria's withdrawal from Jerusalem in 701, the biblical texts juxtapose the assassination story hard on the siege story.  ***Though 20 years apart, the biblical writers seem to link the siege and assassination, perhaps for theological reasons.***  The Babylonian version of Sennacherib's death is also theological, in their telling payback for his theft of an image of Marduk during the final siege on Babylon.  A later [Jewish legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisroch) also includes stolen property.

Regardless, **the bitter family rivalry that led to Sennacherib's likely assassination is probably best told by [Assyrian sources](http://www.gatewaystobabylon.com/introduction/murderersennacherib.htm).**  Their history was not the primary interest of biblical writers.

Comment: Interestingly, the records of Sennacherib inflate the amount of tribute and omit the defeat... but does specifically mention Jerusalem wasn't taken. It's likely that the death of Sennacherib was mentioned in the biblical account to emphasize that He never took Jerusalem in his lifetime. No time period is mentioned. It just says it happened later. The details of the rest of his reign didn't really matter to Jerusalem. Apparently they didn't think they needed to worry about his return.

Answer (score -1):

> In the month of Nisan . . . I made my joyful entrance into the royal palace, the awesome place wherein abides the fate of kings. A firm determination fell upon my brothers. They forsook the gods and returned to their deeds of violence, plotting evil . . . . They revolted. To gain the kingship they slew Sennacherib, their father (Caiger 1944, 161-162).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  Please consider [registering an account](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer.  Also, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and in particular what constitutes a good answer.  While a quote from a reliable source is good *part* of an answer, we generally expect at least some original content too (e.g. analysis or summary).

Answer (score -2):

> 32 Therefore thus said YHVH concerning the sovereign of Ashshur, ‘He does not come into this city, nor does he shoot an arrow there, nor does he come before it with shield, nor does he build a siege mound against it.
>   33 ‘By the way that he came, by the same he turns back. And he does not come into this city,’ declares YHVH.
>   34 ‘And I shall defend this city, to save it for My own sake and for the sake of Daud My servant.’ ”
>   35 And it came to be in that lailah that the Messenger of YHVH went out, and smote in the camp of Ashshur 185,000. And they rose up early in the morning and saw all of them dead bodies.
>   36 And Sankerib sovereign of Ashshur broke camp and went away, and turned back, and remained in Ninuah.
>   37 And it came to be, as he was bowing himself in the house of Nisrok his mighty one, that his sons Adrammelek and Sharetser smote him with the sword, and they escaped into the land of Ararat. And his son Esarkaddon reigned in his place.

Just an observation: King Sankerib and his 3 sons Adrammelek, Sharetser and Esarkaddon are also descenandants of Shem same as Yahuda and it's king Hezekayah. The 2 sons who murdered the king may have hated their dad's stubbornness and rebellion against the Most High. They may have heard and taken notice of YHVH deeds on behalf of His people and against all adversaries. Maybe they had a secret zeal for YHVH in their heart and warned their dad in vain. ho knows.

Another angle to the matter: the 2 sons fled to the Land of Ararat, today's Turkey. They may have hated king Hezekayah along with their father but did not want to continue in Assyria and see their father killed by King Hezekayah. So they may have killed their father out of pity and fled to today's Turkey. Will their off springs fulfill any role in the end times considering the prophecy concerning the Assyrian? who knows?

Comment: Where are the descendants of Sankerib today?

Comment: This post contains a number of conjectures that are not supported by any citations of archaeological or historical evidence, citations from historical literature, or outside scholarly opinion.